# Equation solving by using Python or model builder in ArcMap 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I want to solve one formula in ArcMap 9.3 by using Python or Model builder. I have one shapefile, in that there is in attribute table for field A & B

Solve the formula: `A*B/Sum(A)`. where Sum(A) is total of Field A.

Answer (score 1):

I would use below code-

```
import arcpy,sys
summed_total = 0 ## sum of A
A = "FMeasu" ## your field to be multiplied
B = "Tmeasure"  ##
fc = r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\d\hi.shp" ##change your path to feature class

curS=arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for i in curS:
    summed_total = summed_total+i.getValue(A)
del i,curS

##Add field which contains result of multiplication
arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"Equation","DOUBLE",10,10,20,"Equation","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","")


##Multiplication operation
curU=arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for i in curU:
    i.setValue("Equation",(i.getValue(A)*i.getValue(B))/summed_total)
    curU.updateRow(i)
del i,curU
```